# Future[List[Option[List[Double]]] to Future[Option[List[List[Double]]] in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to transform a `List[Option[List[Double]]]` to a `Option[List[List[Double]]]` that yields `None` if one of the options fails (encapsulated in a `Future`).  Normally I should be able to use `.sequence` from the Scalaz lib. However, when I have the following problem:

```
val matrix = for {
  listOfOptions <- futureListOfOptions
  optionOfList <- listOfOptions.sequence
} yield optionOfList
```

`matrix: Future[Nothing]`
`listOfOptions:  scala.List[Option[scala.List[Double]]]`
`optionOfList: Any`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- I think most wrong thing is having types like `Future[List[Option[List[Double]]]`, you should better flatten them.

Comment: In my case if one option fails I want it to yield `None`, if I flatten it I don't have that. I have this "mess" since it comes from the the values of a `Map` that are of type `Future[Option[List[Double]]]` (query to a server for a vector, hence the future).

Comment: It should be good, maybe it's your IDE which is lost ? try typing matrix in the val declaration I'd say.

Comment: ? this makes no sense.. "if one option fails"?

Comment: What are your types of everything and your desired type of `matrix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably missing some import, or inferring type manually when using just `sequence`. Use `sequenceU` if you want compiler to try it for you.
This works for me:

```
val start: List[Option[List[Double]]] = ???
  import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
  import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
  import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

  val end: Option[List[List[Double]]] = start.sequenceU
```

Full example:

```
  val fstart: Future[List[Option[List[Double]]]] = ???
  import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance

  val matrix = for {
    lo ← fstart
    ol = lo.sequenceU
  } yield ol
```

Answer (score 2):

Future[List[Option[List[Double]]] ->
Future[List[List[Double]]]

```
val x: Future[List[Option[List[Double]]]
val y: Future[List[List[Double]]] = x.map(_.flatten)
```

Why do you need to wrap this in an option?
Just map the list and if it has no elements, then well, it does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like below?

```
val x:List[Option[List[Double]]] = List(Some(List(1.0)),Some(List(2.0)),None)
val y:Option[List[List[Double]]] = {
      val k = x.filter(m => m.isDefined).map(m => m.get)
      if (k.length>0) 
        Some(k)
      else 
        None
}
```

Comment: `val k = x.filter(m => m.isDefined).map(m => m.get)` is bad